# reading Perl CGI param(input)

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm trying to split a $string that is inputted into a webform made using CGI.pm

The split is on '>' and I have it working from the command line using shift to get the file into the script however using the webform doesn't work  - i.e. I get no output. This works from the command line using shift to get the read in the file as follows:

```
my $inFile = shift; 
open (IN, "$inFile");
$/ = ">";
while ( my $record = <IN> ) {
chomp $record; 
my ($defLine, @seqLines) = split /\n/, $record;
my $sequence = join('',@seqLines);
```

however, using the code below in a cgi script does not work - I guess the cgi script is forcing a $string? but I'm not sure how to proceed

```
use CGI qw(:cgi-lib :standard);
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
my $seq = param('sequence');
$/ = ">";
chomp $seq; 
my ($defLine, @seqLines) = split /\n/, $seq;
```

any advice, greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have for a file:

```
local $/ = ">";
while (my $record = <IN>) {
   chomp($record);
   my ($defLine, @seqLines) = split /\n/, $record;
   my $sequence = join('',@seqLines); 
   ...
}
```

Equivalent for a string:

```
for my $record (split />/, $sequence) {
   my ($defLine, @seqLines) = split /\n/, $record;
   my $sequence = join('',@seqLines); 
   ...
}
```

Comment: how can I loop through each string $record, similarly to how I would use the while (my $record = <IN>)